# How do these particular assembler directives (using db and dw) cause a computer to reboot?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

How can these 3 assembler directives cause a computer to reboot?

```
db 0x0ea 
dw 0x0000 
dw 0xffff
```

I found this from http://fisnikhasani.com/building-your-own-bootloader/

As far as my understanding goes, these 3 instructions send you to `FFFF:0000`, the end of memory which causes a reboot by calling BIOS POST. But shouldn't there be a `jmp` instruction in order to make that jump?

Also, it seems to me that in `db 0x0ea`, ea is the machine instruction for `jmp`. If so, how can `db 0x0ea` write machine instruction? If `db` and `dw` have other functions apart from declaring variables, what are they? Can someone please point me to more literature surrounding `db` and `dw` and any of its hidden functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think what does "declaring variables" mean in the context of assembly. `db` and `dw`, when a value is provided, write that value straight into memory. Code, on the other hand, is stored in the memory as, well, bytes. You can fill memory with bytes by having an assembler process your assembly source, or you can look up instruction encoding and fill memory with bytes by db/dw/dd commands.

That's what they're doing here. This sequence of bytes - ea 00 00 ff ff - encodes the `jmp far 0ffffh:0` command.

Comment: Also note that if you need to insert instructions like this (rather than being able to do something like `jmp far 0xFFFF:0x0000`), then the assembler you're using is so bad that it's not worth using and you should find a decent assembler instead.

Comment: so, as an indirect use of these db and dw, I can possibly write a whole program by keying in the hex codes for each instruction and its data, using db, dw, dd, etc... am I right?

Comment: @grammar if done properly, yes - although you must be very careful to encode the instruction bits correctly.  Put it this way, if you took a file and looked at it's hex bits, then set your assembler directives up correctly and made enough `db`'s to clone the original file, when you assemble it, you should get the same file - a program or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can hard-code instructions by simply inserting the proper bits using certain assembler directives (`db`, `dw`, etc...).  In 16-bit mode, the bytes `$EA0000FFFF` disassembles to:

```
ljmp $0xffff,$0x0
```

Which places the value `$FFFF` in the `CS` (code segment) register, and `$0000` in the `IP` (instruction pointer).  This effectively starts executing code from the computer's [reset vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset_vector), which should proceed to boot the system as if you just turned it on.

Answer (score 0):

`db` and `dw` are not assembly instructions, they are *pseudo* instructions. Their arguments are simply used to initialize the byte or word allocated by the pseudo instruction. When they are used in a code segment, they can be used to create executable code.